# Escaping underscores in grails criteria LIKE

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria

We have some simple domain objects that we are doing like statements on.  The data in the table often has underscores in this.  The problem is, underscore is a wildcard character in oracle when used in a like statement.  So far this is the closes piece I've found, but it doesn't seem to work quite right.

```
MyDomain{
def columnOne
def columnTwo
}

def results = myDomain.createCriteria().list(max:10, offset:10){
ilike("columnTwo","%BOB\_%")
sqlRestriction("ESCAPE \\")
}
```

The SQL that is being executed is

```
select count(*) as y0_ from MY_SCHEMA.MY_DOMAIN this_ where
lower(this_.COLUMN_TWO) like ?
and ESCAPE '\'
```

It appears that the sqlRestriction clause is being tagged on as an AND in the query.  Is there a way to avoid this or is there a better way to format the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the like as sqlRestriction and add the escape in the string as you can see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673508/using-hibernate-criteria-is-there-a-way-to-escape-special-characters).

```
def results = myDomain.createCriteria().list(max:10, offset:10){
  sqlRestriction("lower(column_two) like '%bob\_%' ESCAPE '\\' ")
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  Thanks!