# Hibernate criteria accepting %% value

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, hibernate-criteria

I am using the below Hibernate code to filter `workFlowName`.

```
crt.add(Restrictions.like("workFlowName", workFlow, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
// crt is the criteria
```

The problem is when I pass the value to **workFlow** from web (TextBox).it fetching the value correctly (I am passing **`sym`** in text box if fetch 10 records.if i pass the same value like **`%sym%`** again it is fetching same record).

Whether the criteria will omit when it see `%%` as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate does not escape special chars in *like* (e.g. the percentage **`%`** sign). But there are descriptions how to solve it *(escape it)*:

- [Escaping special characters in Hibernate queries](http://blog.abelsky.com/2014/04/07/escaping-special-characters-in-hibernate-queries/)
- [Using hibernate criteria, is there a way to escape special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673508/1679310)
- [Escape special characters in hibernate criteria](http://javanj2ee.blogspot.ru/2010/03/escape-special-characters-in-hibernate.html)

In general we could implement our own **`EscapedILikeExpression`**  (taken from the first link above)

```
class EscapedILikeExpression extends IlikeExpression {
    private static final String HIBERNATE_ESCAPE_CHAR = "\\";

    public EscapedILikeExpression(String propertyName, Object value) {
        super(propertyName, value);
    }

    public EscapedILikeExpression(String propertyName, String value, MatchMode matchMode) {
        super(propertyName, replaceAll(value), matchMode);
    }

    private static String replaceAll(String value) {
        return value
                .replace("\\",  HIBERNATE_ESCAPE_CHAR + "\\")
                .replace("_",   HIBERNATE_ESCAPE_CHAR + "_")
                .replace("%",   HIBERNATE_ESCAPE_CHAR + "%");

    }
}
```

and

```
public class EscapedRestrictions {
    public static Criterion ilike(String propertyName, String value) {
        return new EscapedILikeExpression(propertyName, value);
    }

    public static Criterion ilike(String propertyName, String value, MatchMode matchMode) {
        return new EscapedILikeExpression(propertyName, value, matchMode);
    }
}
```

And now we should be able to call

```
crt.add(EscapedRestrictions.ilike("workFlowName", workFlow, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

Comment: Then how it fetching the record even if pass %sym%.It should return with empty values right ?

Comment: The point is, that if we want symbols like % to be used for filtering ... we have to escape them. With SQL Server I changed them from % into `[%]`... and then only value which contains that would be returned. I.e. if we would use [%]sym[%] with SQL server, only records with these will be found, because it will be converted into SQL statement `WHERE x like '%[%]sym[%]%'`

Comment: Thanks Radim Köhler.Now i got it .

Comment: That's great! really. Enjoy awesome Hibernate, sir;)

Comment: Doesn't work on db2
`<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>`
is set