# Groovy search is not including "_" with criteria "ilike"

Tags: groovy, grails-orm, criteria

I have a search functionality for a domain. While searching with characters it is working fine, but when tried with "_" it is not working as expected.
My search criteria is either "code" or "name" like :

```
def searchKeyword = PERCENT+keyword+PERCENT
def studentList = Student.createCriteria().list (max: max, offset: offset) {
  or {
    ilike "name", searchKeyword
    ilike "code", searchKeyword
  }
  order "code", "asc"
}
```

When I tried to search with "test"

The result is working fine.

```
1. Test
2. TestName
3. Test_Name1
4. Name_test_2
...
```

But when I tried to search with "test_"

The result is :

```
1. TestName
2. Test_Name1
3. Name_test_2
...
```

But my expected result is :

```
1. Test_Name1
2. Name_test_2
...
```

But when I tried to search with "test_N"

The result is :

```
1. Test_Name1
```

Why search with "_" at beginning and end is not considering? How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't some databases treat underscores as wildcards for a single character?  Try escaping the underscore with `\\_`

Comment: @tim_yates : sorry i didn't get you, could you please lemme know with a line of code. :(

Comment: Search for `"test\\_"`

Comment: But I need to search without "_" also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673508/using-hibernate-criteria-is-there-a-way-to-escape-special-characters

Comment: @tim_yates : thnqq... will check this one.