# '&' character in Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, criteria

We want to formulate hibernate criteria query where we can escape & character.We are using Oracle database.

In oracle ampersand is the special character.For example , 
if Company is a db table and it has a column named company_name .There is every possibility that a company name can have &, like 'a&b Inc'.
A hibernate criteria like this is not working.

```
 Criterion criterion = Restrictions.eq("company_name", "a&b Inc").ignoreCase();
return cr.add(criterion);
```

When I execute this , although there are company name column values that matched "a&b Inc" it not returning  any value.

I tried to look other answers in stack overflow , but didn't help me much.Please help me understand in how do this.

I referred to this 
[Using hibernate criteria, is there a way to escape special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673508/using-hibernate-criteria-is-there-a-way-to-escape-special-characters)
But didn't really understand on how to use it.Any example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Escape `&`.

Replace

`Criterion criterion = Restrictions.eq("company_name", "a&b Inc").ignoreCase();`

with

`Criterion criterion = Restrictions.eq("company_name", "a\\&b Inc").ignoreCase();`